# What should the xcode bundle ID or Cordova App ID be if you have a .co.uk domain?

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I'm starting out in Cordova building an iOS app, I understand that with cordova (the APP ID) and with Xcode (Bundle ID) it should be your domain backwards.... My domain is a .co.uk domain so should I use uk.co.mycompany.appname or couk.mycompany.appname or uk.co.mycompany.appname? I have tried using uk.co.mycompany.appname which I found advised in an apple developer forum, but this isn't accepted using the cordova create command as I get the error 'App id contains a reserved word, or is not a valid identifier.' it works if I use com.mycompany.appname but this is actually incorrect as it isn't my domain.

I'm assuming it doesn't really matter and that the idea of using the backwards domain is that you won't conflict with someone elses somewhere along the line, so what is the requirement/etiquette here? What do other people with a .co.uk domain use?

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The app ID is used to identify each app uniquely and therefore should be based on your company domain to avoid conflicts. In your case you are fine with`uk.co.mycompany.appname`.